# Can't enable the firewall on an Proxmox Virtual Environment LXC container via the HTTP API

Tags: curl, virtualization, lxc, proxmox

I can't enable the firewall on an LXC container via the HTTP API (container level firewall not vNIC firewall).

I've been referencing these two links: [PVE-API-Viewer](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs-7/api-viewer/index.html#/nodes/%7Bnode%7D/lxc/%7Bvmid%7D/firewall/options) and [PVE-API](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API) but alas to no avail. I don't understand why when executing a GET request to the firewall/options, the answer includes only a digest and not all the information as per API-Viewer RAW. Also, every try of posting enable=1 returns 501, yet if I enable the firewall in the UI or via
`pvesh /nodes/ASDF/lxc/9999/firewall/options -enable 1` the REST GET to firewall/options returns besides the digest, and also the option "enable": "1".

Below is a snippet of what I tried:

```
APIRSPNS=$(curl -fk -d "username=$PM_USER" --data-urlencode "password=$PM_PASS" "${PM_API_URL}/access/ticket")
CSRFTKN=$(echo $APIRSPNS | jq -r '.data.CSRFPreventionToken')
TKT=$(echo $APIRSPNS | jq -r '.data.ticket')
curl -sSkX GET -b "PVEAuthCookie=${TKT}" "${PM_API_URL}/nodes/ASDF/lxc/9999/firewall/options"
curl -sSkX POST -b "PVEAuthCookie=${TKT}" -H "CSRFPreventionToken: ${CSRFTKN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"data":{"enable": "1"}}' "${PM_API_URL}/nodes/ASDF/lxc/9999/firewall/options"
{"data":null}
curl -fkX POST -b "PVEAuthCookie=${TKT}" -H "CSRFPreventionToken: ${CSRFTKN}" -H "Content-type: application/json" --data '{"enable": "1"}' "${PM_API_URL}/nodes/ASDF/lxc/9999/firewall/options"
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 501
```